# Create an MX record alias?

Tags: mx-record

I have a domain example "copperwidgetmakers.com" for this domain, I get mail at washers@copperwidgetmakers.com. A few months ago we got annoyed at typing this in twitter and other sites and we registered "cuwgtmkr.co".

1. I easily found the way to point all web traffic to cuwgtmkr.co --> copperwidgetmakers.com this works great.
   Now my boss wants emails to do the same...

Is there any trick to doing this? How can I mangle the MX records to do this?

mail to washers@cuwgtmkr.co ---> washers@copperwidgetmakers.com.

I know I can just forward mail via a mail server but the short url only has very basic domain features, DNS, Mail MX and that's about it.

Comment: The MX record for the new domain could be set to the same as the MX on the existing domain, which would direct mail to the same server, but the server would most likely require additional configuration to allow it to accept mail for the new domain and deliver it to the existing mailboxes. Could you provide a little more detail on your mail system? Do you manage it, or is it a service you pay for? What is the platform? Exchange, Office 365, postfix, Gmail?

Comment: It's a paid service, so I have very little control over the mail configuration on the existing domain/host.

Comment: If you are willing to pay for a service, why not pay for one that does what you want it to do? Anyway - You can't do this with MX records. The best way is if you control the email server for copperwidgetmakers.com, give both domains the same MX record and make the email server accept \@cuwgtmkr.co email as well. If you can't do that, and your provider can't have mailboxes \@cuwgtmkr.co forward to your other addresses, then you'll have to forward it via another mail server instead.

Comment: @jcooper If you can tell us which service it is, we may be able to offer some specific advice on how to configure it to accept an additional domain